# Reset form fields to default values in AutoStore scripts

Tags: javascript

The AutoStore knowledgebase articles found by Google seem to be unaccessible so I try it here:

Do you know a way to reset all fields in an AutoStore form after the user has scanned a document?

Comment: What's AutoStore?  What's an AutoStore form?  What's an AutoStore script?  Are you talking about [NSi AutoStore](http://kb.nsiautostore.com/display/kbd/Capture)?

Comment: Yes, the tag wiki is still awaiting approval but it is about capturing using Scanners / multi-funtion devices, and on-device user forms to enter additional document data